# Pass number of clicks to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, pass-data

Here is the case: I have 3 activities, first one contains a button and a TextView which displays a number of this button clicks. Second activity looks the same and it has to receive the number of clicks from the first one and increase it +1 if it is own button is clicked and then pass it to the third activity and so on. How to manage this? Thanks in advance.

So if I click button in first activity, the second activity should show '1', if i then click button in second activity as well, third activity should show '2'

Tab1:

```
public class Tab1 extends Activity {

ImageButton button1;    
int count = 0;
TextView t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab1);

    button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Tab1.this, Tab2.class);
            startActivity(firstIntent);

            TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);
                t.setText("score: " + ++count +"/18");

                finish();
        }
    });                 

           } }
```

Tab2:

```
 public class Tab1 extends Activity {

ImageButton button1;    
int count = 0;
TextView t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab2);

    button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Tab1.this, Tab2.class);
            startActivity(firstIntent);

            TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);
                t.setText("score: " + ++count +"/18");

                finish();
        }
    });                 

           } }
```

Tab3 looks the same

Comment: it's very simple. try this with explicit intent and passed your count value into bundle

Answer (score 1):

In the first activity, you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Your 2nd Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("CountNum", "you count number");
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the 2nd activity inside oncreate, you will use:

```
int count = getIntent().getIntExtra("CountNum", 0);
```

Now, you got the count from the first activity but you will need to pass in to the third activity like in the first step:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Your 3nd Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("CountNum", count );
startActivity(intent);
```

then you will read the count in the third activity using the same way

```
int count = getIntent().getIntExtra("CountNum", 0);
```

You can modify the count value inside the activity as you like.

Comment: intent.putExtra("CountNum", ++count);  instead of " "

Comment: Could you please help me to connect this to my code? I have the following: button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button2);
  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Tab2.this, Tab3.class);
    
    Tab2.this.startActivity(firstIntent);
    
    
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);
       t.setText("score: " + ++count +"/18");
       
       finish();

Comment: i added more details to the answer above. Try it.

Comment: @MinaTadros Please take a look to my code, I am a bit confused, how can I apply your solution and increase value with each clicks in next activities? Sorry for my stupidity..

Comment: no problem, In the first activity, you code will be :
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { @Override    public void onClick(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub Intent firstIntent = new Intent(Tab2.this, Tab3.class); 
firstIntent .putExtra("CountNum", count ); this.startActivity(firstIntent);  
finish();
}

In you second activity, inside onCreate method do:
int count = getIntent().getIntExtra("CountNum", 0);
Then print the value inside count, you will find it the same value you passed in the first activity

Comment: Well, it kinda works, but there is another problem now, hot to continue counting?

Comment: you will make the same thing in activity two. Before calling the method startActivity() inside activity two use this line intent.putExtra("CountNum", count ); and inside oncreate for the third activity, use this line int count = getIntent().getIntExtra("CountNum", 0);
If you did that, you will be got the count value which passed in the first activity. You can modify the count value inside any of those activities as you like